# vim 73 build hasn't enable lua

Tags: vim

In the src/Makefile, I have uncomment the attribute `CONF_OPT_LUA` & `CONF_OPT_LUA_PREFIX`

```
CONF_OPT_LUA = --enable-luainterp
#CONF_OPT_LUA = --enable-luainterp=dynamic
# Lua installation dir (when not set uses $LUA_PREFIX or defaults to /usr)
CONF_OPT_LUA_PREFIX = --with-lua-prefix=/usr/local
```

prefix keeps the defalut

```
# Uncomment the next line to install Vim in your home directory.
#prefix = $(HOME)
```

Lua has been installed on my machine:

```
root@flyingfisher-virtual-machine:/Work1/vim# lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

But after make and install:

```
root@flyingfisher-virtual-machine:/Work1/vim# vi --version | grep lua
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape

[flyingfisher@bin] $which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
```

I don't know why this happened? Did someone meets this quesion?

Comment: Does running the command `which vim` give you `/usr/local/bin/vim`?

Comment: I reconfirm the vim path and it's /usr/local/bin/vim

Comment: Do you have the dev package of lua installed?

Comment: @romainl，I install it by apt-get install liblua5.1*.   I'll have a try install it by source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At src/auto/config.log， you could find the error msg.
In my environment , it is LUA_PREFIX didn't defined in $PATH

By the way,when you modify the src/Makefile to changed the option,then you just need make and make install. ./configure with no option will overwrite everything you made in Makefile.

Everytime you change the Makefile, you should make reconfig again.

PS:you could see all happened in src/auto/config.log

Comment: By the way,you should download lua-5.1.4, but not lua-5.2.2 src package .It looks that lua-5.2.2 has removed LUA_ENVIRONINDEX"

Comment: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source also give me some help.   you shoud use lua-5.1.4 but not lua-5.2.2 which remove LUA_ENVIRONINDEX

Comment: Just exported via `export LUA_PREFIX="$DIR"` and everything compiles like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The version you compiled should be installed at `/usr/local/bin/vim` run that by invoking it with the full path. `which vim` will tell you which `vim` installation is run when invoked without a path.

Comment: i confirm it and also the lua is disbaled